# Ruby on Rails - Rtesseract not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, tesseract

I am trying to deploy on Heroku RTesseract feature to read text on image.

I add the gem into the Gemfile

```rb
gem 'rtesseract'
```

I implemented the feature into the `PagesController#home` (sure it is dirty but it is for testing before adding to my real app)

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home 
    image = RTesseract.new('https://www.drillster.com/info/img/screenshot-ticket-received.en.png')
    @result = image.to_s
  end
end
```

It is working well on `http://localhost:3000/`. I can see the text printing of the page

[image]

When I deploy on Heroku, I have add the following buildpacks :

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/pathwaysmedical/heroku-buildpack-tesseract
```

When I start my application on Heroku, I can see the error :

```
Tesseract::Error (Cannot open input file: 
https://www.drillster.com/info/img/screenshot-ticket-received.en.png)
```

The error is raising when the code executed the line `@result = image.to_s`

If someone has already solve this issue, it will be really nice to help me !

Thanks in advance for your help & reading !

Comment: Does the buildpack actually work? You can see if the library is actually finding it by calling `RTesseract.check_version!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like they added libcurl to get images from URLS in this commit here:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/commit/286d8275c783062057d09bb8e5e6607a8917abd9

That was in OCT 2019

Looking in the changelog here:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/ChangeLog

We see that version 2018-10-29 - V4.0.0

the version in that buildpack is:
https://github.com/pathwaysmedical/heroku-buildpack-tesseract/blob/master/tesseract-ocr-4.0.tar.gz

So I'm guessing that the buildpack version doesn't support getting the image via URL. I bet when you run it locally you have 4.1 and not the older 4.0?

You could fork that buildpack, get the latest source and compile it with libcurl, or you could try download it to a tempfile and then pass that tempfile location to the library. Though that's not awesome for a variety of reasons and you probably want to delete it when you're done.

If I'm wrong about the version numbers please let me know.

If you install httparty, you could do something like this to test it

```
url = 'https://www.drillster.com/info/img/screenshot-ticket-received.en.png'
File.open("/tmp/test_file.jpg", "wb") do |f| 
      f.write HTTParty.get(url).body
end
image = RTesseract.new('/tmp/test_file.jpg')
image.to_s
# "Requested ticket\n\nTo make this test, a user must have a ticket....."
```